# VueJS and Axios communication with PHP returns PHP file as string

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

Ive setup an application with the following technologies being used:

- VueJS
- Axios for HTTP calls
- PHP

Im using PHP with the normal Apache 24 webserver - The setup seems to be completed. Ive created an index.php inside of the htdocs folder. Furthermore I can open this .php file and get some infos about everything.

index.php

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

I created the following file in the same folder:

Login.php

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $validUsername = 'test';
    $validPassword = 'test';
    $input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $username = $input['username'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $data = array();

    $is_available = '0';
    if (($username === $validUsername) && ($password === $validPassword)) {
        $is_available = '1';
    }

    $data = array(
        'success'  => $is_available
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I want to communicate with this php-script via VueJS and Axios. So Ive created the following file:
Javascript part of Login.vue

```
 <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          username: "",
          password: "",
          visible: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        async login() {
          await this.axios
            .post("backend/user_handling/Login.php", {
              username: this.username,
              password: this.password,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
              if (response.data.success) {
                // Handle successful login
                console.log("Login successful");
              } else {
                // Handle login error
                console.error("Login failed");
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("An error occurred:", error);
            });
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

But the result of the login function is the whole Login.php in plain text format:
[image]

My first thought was that php isnt installed correctly, but then the index.php shouldnt work too ... I dont know how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

PS: Axios in imported in main.js like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

Comment: This most likely is a configuration issue with the webserver. Where is you `index.php` file located? If you move this one into the `backend/user_handlig` folder and try to fetch it from your browser - does it work?

Comment: @Cyclonecode Yeah its also in the same folder  - I can open it in the browser fully working. I also can open the Login.php in the browser and it returns "success: 0"  (I replaced the $input with some dummy data)

Comment: I have been looking more into this. Are you webserver on the same domain as your vue application? If not  then you need to add the real URL when doing the request e.g `http://localhost:8080/backend_user_handling/Login.php`, you will also need to setup the server to respond with the valid headers e.g `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and so on.
Notice, that if you are running your vue app on `http://localhost:5174` and make a request to `backend/user_handling/Login.php` it will then try to use the same domain e.g `http://localhost:5174`, which probably is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Cyclonecode that was the problem! Can u post it as Answer so I can accept it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking into this. Are you webserver on the same domain as your vue application? If not then you need to add the real URL when doing the request e.g `http://localhost:8080/backend_user_handling/Login.php`, you will also need to setup the server to respond with the valid headers e.g `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and so on.

Notice, that if you are running your vue app on `http://localhost:5174` and make a request to `backend/user_handling/Login.php` it will then try to use the same domain e.g `http://localhost:5174`, which probably is not what you want.